# Converted function component (toggle button with role permissions) stopped working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components

I had to convert my class component into function component since I will have to use hooks for redux(useDispatch();)
Everything seemed okay except the thing that toggle button doesnt want to work.
As a comparison I post a class component code(a bit of it) and function component code(more of it)

```
 state = {
    open: true,
    role: ""
}


 componentDidMount() {
 if (this.props.auth.user) 
{
this.setState({role: this.props.auth.user.role});
 }
 }

 checkRole = (role) => {
 if (role === 'Menager' || role === 'Technolog')
  {
  return true }
else 
{
  return false
};
}

toggleImage = () => {
if(this.checkRole(this.state.role)) {
this.setState({open: !this.state.open})
};
}
```

And here is the function component code:

```
 const Islbutton = props => {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
 const [role, setRole] = useState('');



 useEffect(() => {
 if (props.auth.user) 
 {
 setRole({role: props.auth.user.role});
   }
 });


 const checkRole = (role) => {
 if (role === 'Menager' || role === 'Technolog')
  {
   return true }
 else 
{
  return false
};
}

  const toggleImage = () => {
 if(checkRole(role)) {
 setOpen({open: !open})
 };
 }

 const getImageName = () => open ? 'islOnn' : 'islOfff'



        return(

          <div>

            <img style={islplace} src={open ? islon : isloff }  onClick={()=> toggleImage(role)} />
          </div>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initailized your state you made in a way where your `open` state is a boolean primitive

`const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);`

Now the only values for open are either `true` or `false`

Then further in your code you are also expecting to be in this same shape as you can see here.

`const getImageName = () => open ? 'islOnn' : 'islOfff'`

as you can see `open` is not being used as an object.

But in your code where you are actually setting the state you are passing an object to your `setOpen` function as you can see here

`setOpen({open: !open})`

this code should be changed to accept either true or false, and not an object with key of open.

In other words the code can be written like so.

```
 const toggleImage = () => {
 if(checkRole(role)) {
    setOpen(!open) // no {} here its not an object.
  };
 }
```

Comment: I did as you said and it helped me! I figured out by your answer that I have a mistake at useEffect() as well. It should be : setRole(props.auth.user.role) instead of setRole({ role: props.auth.user.role }). Thank you a lot! I have a one little question: Should i get rid of {} while converting from class component to function component in most of the cases?